# Automated Regression Testing for SAP Web Intelligence Reports

Tags: web-application, regression-testing

Looking for a regression testing solution for SAP Web Intelligence Reporting that is fairly low maintenance. Wondering what others recommend for this and have used to accomplish this goal?

Comment: Salmonerd I fear this is too broad to be truly answerable. If you could provide more context about what you're doing and what you've tried, we can take it out of hold status.

Comment: We ended up doing a proof of concept with a piece of software called TestingAnywhere, which worked great for our needs.